# How I can delete specific letters from a string of text?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have to code a program where I have to delete specific letters from a text string.

For example, if the user types in text like `"Hepello Ipe hapeve ape prpeobpelepem"`, the code has to automatically delete the `'pe'` letters so the text becomes the normal `"Hello I have a problem"`.

I tried to program this with the `list` functions, but my teacher said that I HAVE to use pointers and dynamic structures, which I suck at.

Can someone help me?

Here is what I have so far. My 2nd code is still pretty empty:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

list<string> createCodeList()
{
    list<string> codeList;
    string input;

    cout << "Enter your coded text: " << endl;
    getline(cin, input);
   
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 3)
    {
        string code = input.substr(i, 2);
        codeList.push_back(code);
    }

    return codeList;
}

void removeCodeWords(list<string>& codeList)
{
    for (auto it = codeList.begin(); it != codeList.end(); )
    {
        if (*it == "pe")
        {
            it = codeList.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}

void printCodeList(const list<string>& codeList)
{
    for (const string& code : codeList)
    {
        cout << code;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    list<string> codeList = createCodeList();
    removeCodeWords(codeList);
    printCodeList(codeList);
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Codedtext
{
    string text;    
};

typedef Codedtext* point;

point Createlist()
{
    point list = NULL;
    char input;
    cout << "Enter your coded text: " << endl;
    cin >> input;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `std::string` seems contrary to your requirements. Although it is a **"** dynamic structure **"**, one wouldn't use pointers with it.

Comment: Your code is all over the place, pointers aside. Why are you using a `std::list` when you seem to only need a `std::string` for the task? At that, `std::cin >> input` is fundamentally wrong for inputting a string. You need to learn some fundamental stuff before you do this assignment. If this is part of a set of lessons, those lessons are not very good.

Comment: @lakeweb Judging the lessons alone based on *this* question is a big leap.

Comment: My input, given what I perceive the requirements to be, would be to read the full line into a C-string. Then scan the string for your glyph, "pe" and record all occurrences. Then write a function that can remove and re-arrange the string. And call it from the end, moving toward the beginning of the string. Better though, I could spend a bit of time writing a tiny erase/remove function. Might even be a 'one-liner.' But that wouldn't meet the fuzzy (as provided here) requirements.

Comment: Hi @sweenish, yes. I may be very wrong. But something is very out of place by the look of the code.

Comment: @lakeweb And that's on whoever wrote the code.

Comment: This is a good question to ask your teacher.

Comment: @sweenish Based on requirements it looks like they are learning C-style C++. I would argue that this is not correct approach to learn "modern C++".

Comment: @sklott C-style C++ is not a correct approach, this is true. It's still a leap to use paraphrased requirements as the basis of assumption. Even when teaching modern C++, students still need to know what pointers and dynamic structures are. I suppose the point I'm getting at is that SO is extremely quick to get on the teachers and material, but less so the student. When I teach, I do teach modern C++. I also cover C-style just because they still have to recognize/know it, but it's never assigned. I guarantee that any of my bad students could ask in a way to make me look utterly incompetent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `std::list` code doesn't work because your `createCodeList()` function is not breaking up the user's input correctly.  It is extracting 2 characters from every group of 3 characters, regardless of where the `"pe"` substrings are actually located (hint: they are NOT located at even intervals of 3 characters).

IOW, you are breaking up the input like this:

`Hep|ell|o I|pe |hap|eve| ap|e p|rpe|obp|ele|pem`

`Hep` -> `He`
`ell` -> `el`
`o I` -> `o` 
`pe`  -> `pe` (removed)
`hap` -> `ha`
`eve` -> `ev`
 `ap` ->  `a`
`e p` -> `e` 
`rpe` -> `rp`
`obp` -> `ob`
`ele` -> `el`
`pem` -> `pe` (removed)

So your output ends up as:

> Heelo haev ae rpobel

Whereas the correct breakup would look like this instead (note the groupings are NOT the same length):

`He|pe|llo I|pe| ha|pe|ve a|pe| pr|pe|ob|pe|le|pe|m`

`He`
`pe` (removed)
`llo I`
`pe` (removed)
 `ha`
`pe` (removed)
`ve a`
`pe` (removed)
 `pr`
`pe` (removed)
`ob`
`pe` (removed)
`le`
`pe` (removed)
`m`

So the output would be:

> Hello I have a problem

See the difference?

With that said, try this instead:

```
list<string> createCodeList()
{
    list<string> codeList;
    string input;

    cout << "Enter your coded text: " << endl;
    getline(cin, input);
   
    string::size_type start = 0, end;
    while ((end = input.find("pe", start)) != string::npos)
    {
        codeList.push_back(input.substr(start, end-start));
        codeList.push_back("pe");
        start = end + 2;
    }
    if (start < input.size())
        codeList.push_back(input.substr(start));

    return codeList;
}
```

Now the rest of your code will work as expected.

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/l7ddhy)

That being said, since your teacher doesn't want you to use `std::list`, you could simply implement the linked-list yourself, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Codedtext
{
    string text;
    Codedtext* next = nullptr;
};

using CodedtextPtr = Codedtext*;

CodedtextPtr createCodeList()
{
    CodedtextPtr codeList = nullptr;
    CodedtextPtr *node = &codeList;
    string input;

    cout << "Enter your coded text: " << endl;
    getline(cin, input);
   
    string::size_type start = 0, end;
    while ((end = input.find("pe", start)) != string::npos)
    {
        *node = new Codedtext{ input.substr(start, end-start) };
        node = &((*node)->next);

        *node = new Codedtext{ "pe" };
        node = &((*node)->next);

        start = end + 2;
    }
    if (start < input.size())
        *node = new Codedtext{ input.substr(start) };

    return codeList;
}

void removeCodeWords(CodedtextPtr& codeList)
{
    CodedtextPtr* previous = &codeList;
    
    for(auto it = codeList; it != nullptr; )
    {
        CodedtextPtr next = it->next;

        if (it->text == "pe")
        {
            *previous = next;
            delete it;
        }
        else
            previous = &(it->next);

        it = next;
    }
}

void printCodeList(CodedtextPtr codeList)
{
    while (codeList)
    {
        cout << codeList->text;
        codeList = codeList->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void freeCodeList(CodedtextPtr codeList)
{
    while (codeList)
    {
        CodedtextPtr next = codeList->next;
        delete codeList;
        codeList = next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    CodedtextPtr codeList = createCodeList();
    removeCodeWords(codeList);
    printCodeList(codeList);
    freeCodeList(codeList);
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/HA9lG5)